# Is there a linux remote fs driver (nfs/sshfs/cifs/etc) that also keeps a local copy and fails over to the local copy?

Tags: linux, filesystems, failover, remote, synchronization

I need to keep some static web mirrors synced in as close to realtime as possible, but I also want it to be somewhat fail-safe (or at least not obvious to the visitors), so if the file server goes down the mount is automatically switched to the local copy. Is there a fs driver out there that can do that? Simply rsyncing isn't a good choice because of the sheer number of files involved. Failing an fs driver, is there some other solution to this problem?

All the servers in question are linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XtreemFS](http://www.xtreemfs.org/index.php) is a

> "fault-tolerant file system that automatically handles all failure modes — including network splits".

[OfflineFS](http://offlinefs.sourceforge.net/wiki/) aims to

> "extend every filesystem with offline capabilities"

and

> "When connecten is restored, the filesystem automatically synchronizes the files"

I've not tried either, but the [XtreemFS feature set](http://www.xtreemfs.org/all_features.php) looks promising.

Comment: Agreed, XtreemFS looks very, very flexible. After trying it out a bit it looks perfect for my needs. Thanks for pointing it out for me.